# Can't connect to raspberry pi 2 over bluetooth with MIT App Inventor

Tags: raspbian, python, bluetooth

I have a raspberry pi 2 with a bluetooth USB Dongle, and i've been trying for hours to connect it with an app I created on app inventor. The app is simple, just sending a string, and i've tried to open up a serial port in order to recieve the data, but whenever i try to connect the app I get a 507 error, saying device unable to connect, however it's completely fine when sending files and other data? Is there any solution to this, or any other way to send accelerometer information from the phone to the raspberry pi?